# SimpleModal does not size properly with initial load

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, simplemodal

I currently have a generic image loader using simplemodal.

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
   $.modal("<div><img src=\"someimage.jpg\" /></div>");
});
```

The first time I click -- the modal window is incorrect. It is displayed as a small window behind the image.

The second time I click the button -- the modal is the correct. The size of the modal is correct based on the image rendered and image is inside the modal box.

I do not have the option of creating a div with the image and setting the display none property.

any insight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell with the way you are loading the image, SimpleModal is not able to determine it's size.

You have a couple of options...

1) Add an onShow callback and call `$.modal.setContainerDimensions()`

```
$('.clickMe').click(function () {
    $.modal("<div><img src=\"someimage.jpg\" /></div>", {
        onShow: function () {
            $.modal.setContainerDimensions();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

2) Load the image first, then show it:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        $.modal("<div><img src=\"someimage.jpg\" /></div>");
    };
    img.src = 'someimage.jpg';
    return false;
});
```

Both of those should work. Let me know if you have any troubles.

Comment: Eric the issue is definitely associated with the image not loading prior to SimpleModal onShow. Both of these solutions work. I used answer 2! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this code will display image with simplemodal plugin.
I just post here and add a little description.

html:

```
<table class="thumbnail">
  <tr>
   <td>
     <img src="/peopledesign/pictures/1319003385503_thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="/peopledesign/pictures/1319003385503.jpg" class="pixLink">zoom out</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id='pix'>
  <div class='header'><span>#springMessage('display.common.showpix')</span></div>
  <div class='pixframe'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
          function(){
            previewPix($('#project_item_scope a.pixLink,#project_basicinfo_scope a.pixLink'));
          }
  );
</script>
```

javascript which will get link's href property and create a image appending to pixframe div:

```
function previewPix(linkObj){
  linkObj.click(
    function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var imgUrl=$(this).attr('href');
      var dialogDivObj=$('#pix');
      var pixDivObj=$('.pixframe',dialogDivObj);
      pixDivObj.empty(); //clean pix div
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {// first load image and fit its width and height
        var i=$(img);
        i.attr('id', 'pic-image');
        i.width(this.width);
        i.height(this.height);
        var outerHeight = i.outerHeight(true);
        var outerWidth = i.outerWidth(true);
        dialogDivObj.width(outerWidth);
        dialogDivObj.height(outerHeight+30);//30=container header's height
        pixDivObj.append(i);
        showPixDialog(
          dialogDivObj
        );
      }
      img.src=imgUrl;
    }
  );
}

function showPixDialog(dialogDivObj){
  dialogDivObj.modal({
    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
    position: ["10%"],
    overlayId: 'pix-overlay',
    containerId: 'pix-container',
    onShow:function(dialog){
      // important!
      // refere from:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240875/simplemodal-does-not-size-properly-with-initial-load
      dialog.modal.setContainerDimensions();
    }
  });
```

css which modified from SimpleModal's dialog style:

```
/* pix preview dialog */
#pix {display:none;}

/* Overlay */
#pix-overlay {background-color:#eee; cursor:default;}

/* Container */
#pix-container {
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  font:12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Liberation Sans",FreeSans,sans-serif;
  text-align:left;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #F90;
}
#pix-container .header {
  height:30px; line-height:30px; width:100%;
  /*background:url(../../images/simplemodal-header.gif) repeat-x; color:#fff;*/
  background-color:#F90;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#pix-container.header span {padding-left:8px;}
#pix-container.pixframe {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#pix-container a.modal-close,
#pix-container a.modal-close:link,
#pix-container a.modal-close:active,
#pix-container a.modal-close:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:2px;
  color:#fff;
}
#pix-container a.modal-close:hover {color:#ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this: [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) , then try to set `autoResize` to `'true'` in plugin options, like so:

```
$("#sample").modal({
  autoResize:true
 });
```

Also try putting your code into a [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or `window.onload`

Good luck, also maybe try other modal plugins, such as [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: I tried the autoResize property and still have the same issue. Thanks for the input!